# But Juju Quickstart is still a validate solution to use on Ubuntu 16.04Lts?

Tags: juju

I saw Juju Quickstart is still present on official repository of Ubuntu 16.04Lts, but is still a validate solution we can use? 
On its official guide of Juju (ver. 2.0/2.1) it's not present any note about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juju quickstart is a helper application which worked with the previous series of Juju clients (1.x). It is still in the archive for 16.04 because the previous series of Juju is still available there I imagine (the package is called **juju-1.25**).

Most of the functionality of Quickstart has been replaced or is no longer needed, e.g. Juju 2.x can deploy bundles and has interactive helpers for setting up cloud configuration and credentials.